# Adding a new model

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wanted to add another robot to my gazebo project. I downloaded the urdf file and spawned it at the location using rosservice call spawn_sdf_model. But how should I give move commands to it  ? model_name : turtlebot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267128/adding-a-new-model/) by [Jaskirat Singh](https://answers.ros.org/users/30755/jaskirat-singh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried to read the project of mavros?

---

Originally posted by [Bo Shang](https://answers.ros.org/users/31311/bo-shang/) with karma: 16 on 2017-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jaskirat Singh](https://answers.ros.org/users/30755/jaskirat-singh/) on 2017-07-24**:
no . what is that ?

**Comment by [Bo Shang](https://answers.ros.org/users/31311/bo-shang/) on 2017-07-24**:
http://forum.erlerobotics.com/t/how-to-set-and-read-velocity-of-erle-copter-in-the-pattern-follower-simulation/3119/7
Is this what you want?